# Add annotation to specific cells in heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting a seaborn heatmap and would like to annotate only the specific cells with custom text.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO(u'''75,83,41,47,19
                    51,24,100,0,58
                    12,94,63,91,7
                    34,13,86,41,77''')

labels = StringIO(u'''7,8,4,,1
                    5,2,,2,8
                    1,,6,,7
                    3,1,,4,7''')

data = pd.read_csv(data, header=None)
data = data.apply(pd.to_numeric)

labels = pd.read_csv(labels, header=None)
#labels = np.ma.masked_invalid(labels)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(data, annot=labels, ax=ax, vmin=0, vmax=100)
plt.show()
```

The above code generates the following heatmap:

[image: heatmap with nan values]

and the commented line generates the following heatmap:

[image: heatmap with 0 values]

I would like to show only the non-nan (or non-zero) text on the cells. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a string array for `annot` instead of a masked array:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO(u'''75,83,41,47,19
                    51,24,100,0,58
                    12,94,63,91,7
                    34,13,86,41,77''')

labels = StringIO(u'''7,8,4,,1
                    5,2,,2,8
                    1,,6,,7
                    3,1,,4,7''')

data = pd.read_csv(data, header=None)
data = data.apply(pd.to_numeric)

labels = pd.read_csv(labels, header=None)
#labels = np.ma.masked_invalid(labels)

# Convert everything to strings:
annotations = labels.astype(str)
annotations[np.isnan(labels)] = ""

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(data, annot=annotations, fmt="s", ax=ax, vmin=0, vmax=100)
plt.show()
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

To complement the answer by [@mrzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9144990/mrzo), you can use `na_filter=False` in `read_csv()` to store `nan`s as empty strings and use `pandas.DataFrame.astype()` to convert to strings in place:

```py
# ...
labels = pd.read_csv(labels, header=None, na_filter=False).astype(str)
sns.heatmap(data, annot=labels, fmt='s', ax=ax, vmin=0, vmax=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just going to add this as it has taken me some time to work out how to do something similar *programmatically* for a slightly different application: I wanted to suppress 0-values from the annotation, but because the values were arising as the result of a crosstab operation I couldn't use [William Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60611205/4041902)'s nice approach without writing the crosstab out and then reading it back in which seemed... inelegant.

There may be a yet more elegant way to do this, but for me running it through `numpy` was ridiculously fast and quite easy.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

from io import StringIO

data = StringIO(u'''75,83,41,47,19
                    51,24,100,0,58
                    12,94,63,91,7
                    34,13,86,41,77''')

data = pd.read_csv(data, header=None)
data = data.apply(pd.to_numeric)

# For more complex functions you could write a def instead
# of using this simple lambda function
an = np.vectorize(lambda x: '' if x<50 else str(round(x,-1)))(data.to_numpy())

sns.heatmap(
    data=data.to_numpy(), # Note this is now numpy too
    cmap='BuPu',
    annot=an,   # The matching ndarray of annotations
    fmt = '',   # Formats annotations as strings (i.e. no formatting)
    cbar=False, # Seems overkill if you've got annotations
    vmin=0, 
    vmax=data.max().max()
)
```

This can make life a little more difficult in terms of labelling axes, though it's straightforward enough: `ax.set_xticklabels(df.columns.values)`. And if you had axislabels in, say, the first column then you'd need to use `iloc` (`data.iloc[:,1:]`) in your `to_numpy` call, but combined with a custom colormap (e.g. 0==white) you can create heatmaps that are a lot easier to look at.

Obviously the crude rounding is confusing (why does 80 have different shades?) but you get the point:

[image]